# JAVA: Interpreter or compiler? File extension for Java? How to execute?

Tags: java, jar, compilation, interpreter, file-extension

I would like to know about java. So, Java is a compiler or Interpreter? What are its file extension and how to execute a .java or .jar file?

Comment: This should all be explained in the first chapter of your favorite java book.

Comment: is a language, you need to check some beg tutorial and come back with questions related to code

Comment: Java is a language. You compile `.java` files with the `javac` compiler to produce `.class` files. You can run a compiled Java program using `java`. I suggest you start by using an IDE and you won't need this to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is complied , and lets you quickly find syntax issues.
however it is kind of half breed - because it is compiled to what is called "**bytecode**"
when you run the compiled java program the launcher translates/interprets the bytecode to machine code suitable for the O/S you are running on.

FileExtention of the java program (the code as text) is .java
The compilation creates a file (the bytecode) with the extension .class (for example myClass.class)

to **run** the .class file use:  **java myClass**  (*without* the .class extension)

to run a .jar file  run:  **java -jar helloworld.jar**

(note: there are differences between compiling a .java file to  .class,  and packaging compiled java classes into a .jar)

Comment: You don't compile Java code into a JAR. You compile Java source into bytecode (`.class` files). You package compiled bytecode and other resources into a JAR. A JAR is a ZIP file with a specific content layout. A JAR is not a compiler artifact.